# Game takes up only the top right corner of the screen in LIBGDX

Tags: libgdx

I am working on LIBGDX . My game takes up only the top right corner of the screen rather taking up the entire width and height. 
  In my update method of the screen, I have this code,

```
      public void update(float dt) {   
         ......
        gamecam.position.x = this.gamehero.heroBody.getPosition().x; -- 1
        gamecam.position.y = this.gamehero.heroBody.getPosition().y; -- 2
         ......
       }
```

But, when I remove the second line of the code the game takes up the entire screen but the camera doesn't follow the player on y axis . I have attached the screen shot of the game when I include the second line of the code, [image: output]

And, when I remove the second line of code, It takes up the entire screen

[image: output]I don't know how to resolve it. Any suggestions would be better. Thanks

Comment: Seems like you have already answered your question -> just remove the second line :-|

Comment: I said if I remove the second line , the camera doesn't follow the player in y axis. But I need the camera to follow @user3351949

Answer (score 0):

Create your camera with this:

```
gamecam = new OrthographicCamera(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
gamecam.position.set(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2, 0);
```

Update camera `gamecam.update()` after each position editing.

```
public void update(float dt) {   
    gamecam.position.x = this.gamehero.heroBody.getPosition().x; // -- 1
    gamecam.position.y = this.gamehero.heroBody.getPosition().y; // -- 2
    gamecam.update(); // -- 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kolesnikovich is on the right track with the top of his code. But unfortunately positions the camera exactly like you in the end.

What you are actually doing is setting the centered position of the cam. So all you need to do is increment the camera's position coordinates by half the viewport width and height.

```
public void update(float dt) {   
    gamecam.position.x = this.gamehero.heroBody.getPosition().x + 
         gamecam.getViewportWidth / 2;
    gamecam.position.y = this.gamehero.heroBody.getPosition().y +
        gamecam.getViewportHeight / 2;
    gamecam.update(); // -- 3
}
```

Comment: Thanks its working but the viewport is displaying slightly above the ground. ie. part of ground is not shown. Any idea ? @Menno Gouw

Comment: Yeah, right now you are positioning the left/bottom part of the cam at the left bottom part of the character. So if you want to have the camera show an additional tile below the player you can subtract the tile height from the Y position. `gamecam.position.y = this.gamehero.heroBody.getPosition().y +
        gamecam.getViewportHeight / 2 - tileHeight;` Likewise you can do this for the X position of the camera. You basically move the camera with the player, anything you add or subtract is a offset for the camera, like we did before with half the viewport width/height.

Comment: Subtracting with the tileHeight doesn't work . I just used     tilePixelWidth = prop.get("tilewidth", Integer.class); and then subtracted tilePixelWidth for x position as you said but I couldn't see the world either when I use this @Menno Gouw

Comment: If you offset the camera by the height your tile is then that will fix it. It is exactly the same as incrementing width vp width/height. I don't know how you draw your tiles so cannot possibly know  what number to use. Try playing with the offset number. If `prop.get("tilewidth", Integer.class);` returns something like 1000 but when drawing you use 10 it will obviously not work. Stop thinking, it's dead easy: `you set camera middle position at character` then `offset camera by half screen size` and now  just `offset it by the tile size`.